# Access Office356 shared mailbox with PHP

Tags: php, imap

I'm working on a PHP script to read and parse error logs sent to a shared mailbox.

I'm using imap_open() to connect.

If I connect with the following credentials to my own mailbox, it works fine

```
server: {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}
username: myname@domain.com
password: mypas$word
```

However, if I want to connect to the sared mailbox with the follwowing credentials, I get an error

```
server: {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}
username: myname@domain.com\shared-folder@domain.com
password: mypas$word
```

The error is the following: `User is authenticated but not connected. (errflg=2)`

According to my research that would mean I'm using the wrong password, but since it works when connecting to my own inbox, it can't be wrong

I am a 100% certain my account can access the shared mailbox, I can access it via my account through the Office 365 webinterface

One more detail: my password includes a $ sign, but that shouldn't matter. I use single quotes on the password and escaping the $ sign doesn't help, it results in a failed login even for my personal mailbox.

Comment: So what have you done so far?

Comment: This is not really a question of coding, but interpreting Microsoft's error codes.

Comment: Yes, the password WOULD matter, if you're doing `imap_open(...., "mypas$word")`. that'd be the literal string `mypas` and whatever (maybe null) value exists in the variable `$word`.

Comment: When I connect to my own mailbox, I can list all the mails and delete them if I want to. When I want to the shared folder, I don't get further than a failed connection attempt

Comment: I'm using single quotes for the password. Escaping the $ doesn't help. The fact that the password works for my own mailbox convinces me that the password is not the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using the account alias

%USERUPN%/%SHAREDALIAS% for example:-

`user@domain.com/sharedbox` where "sharedbox" is the alias of the shared mailbox instead of the full email address

I've seen different reports of some people using forward slash ( / ) and some using a backslash ( \ )

---

Edit

Are you using the mailbox alias?  Do not use sharedbox@shareddomain.com

Exchange Configuration:

```
  USER EMAIL: user@maindomain.com
  PASSWORD: password



 SHARED MAILBOX: shared@anotherdomain.com      (could also be @domain.com, of course)
  SHARED MAILBOX ALIAS: shared-mailbox
```

Note: Please make sure to create the UNIQUE alias always with the mailbox, because it creates the user [alias]@maindomain.com. In this case shared-mailbox@maindomain.com

Settings for IMAP Configuration:

```
  EMAIL ADDRESS: shared@anotherdomain.com (shared mailbox)
  IMAP SERVER: outlook.office365.com
  SMTP SERVER: smtp.office365.com
  USERNAME: user@maindomain.com\shared-mailbox  (user\shared mailbox alias)
  PASSWORD: password (user's password)
```

Comment: Thanks, but that resulted in a `imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}`. Changing the \ to / doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: I don't have access to the configuration so I've contacted the people who do. I'm not sure if there is an alias configured.

Comment: the alias is currently the same as the name of the inbox, and that doesn't work. I've requested to change the alias to something different

Comment: We finally got this to work by adding `array('DISABLE_AUTHENTICATOR' => 'PLAIN')` to the `imap_open` string. We did also have to create a new shared mailbox, something was wrong with the config of the first one and we couldn't get it to work there.

Comment: What was interesting is that this worked for my on my Windows based development system, but didn't work on my Linux production server.  Ben Sommerville's solution above DID work on my Linux server, though.

Answer (score 8):

Another solution that worked for us is to add the username data to the mailbox  parameter using the appropriate flags.

For example, with the Office 365 configuration of

```
USER EMAIL: user@maindomain.com
PASSWORD: password
SHARED MAILBOX: shared@anotherdomain.com
```

then the imap_open call would be

```
imap_open("{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/authuser=user@maindomain.com/user=shared@anotherdomain.com}", "user@maindomain.com", "password");
```

Note the inclusion of the main user email using the /authuser flag and the shared mailbox using the /user flag.

That worked for us when the mailbox alias approach in the previous answer was not successful.

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work for me. I think this only works for certain server configurations. I get: `Can't do /authuser with this server`

Comment: There is definitely something specific to the server.  FYI this was to connect to an Office 365 Business (Enterprise) account.

I tried every other approach I could find on the internet or think of and this was the only one that worked for this particular case.

There is something about the combination of php imap and exchange/O365 that doesn't play well together :(

Comment: Worked for me, but I used the INBOX suffix for the server address
`{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/authuser=fulluser@email.com/user=fullshared@mail.com}INBOX`

Comment: Worked for me too, but after also added charset  'US-ASCII', to use imap_search with office365