# PHP IMAP with Office365 mail

Tags: php, email, ssl, outlook

I have searched multiple SO topics on my issue, couldn't find any that would resolve my problem. (One similiar one is here: [Access Office356 shared mailbox with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481028/access-office356-shared-mailbox-with-php))

Currently trying to connect with IMAP PHP to an outlook box, I can succesfully add the IMAP box to my mail client (in mac) and receive the e-mail, though when using PHP I cannot seem to get it working.

My code:

```
$hostname = '{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'email@example.com';
$password = 'password';

$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
```

I have also tried adding novalidate-cert etc. doesn't seem to make any difference

Error's that I am getting:

```
 imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX

 [ErrorException]
 imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX
```

Hope anyone can get me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

In office365, you can not open the IMAP for Exchange Online Kiosk Licence ...