# Reading a shared Outlook365 mailbox with Javamail

Tags: email, office365, jakarta-mail, imap, starttls

My company has an outlook mailbox set up to receive data from customers each day. We have a Javamail program set up to read this Exchange mailbox and process each customers' data.

Recently, IT moved almost all of our company mailboxes to Office365. If I change our program to look at my Office365 personal mailbox, this same Javamail program can read my email just fine. However, the mailbox being used for this data is a "shared" mailbox. If I access it over the web at https://outlook.office.com/owa/?realm=company.com, I can click on my avatar and "Open another mailbox", and I can open this mailbox just fine without a password requested.

My problem is that I cannot access this additional mailbox via javamail. It does not have a password, so I cannot login as (shared_mailbox)@company.com. The Microsoft page https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6369118f-7dee-4728-ac1c-a0c706b3d290/office-365-exchange-online-how-to-access-a-shared-mailbox-using-thunderbird-or-other-imap-client?forum=onlineservicesexchange suggests that I login as (my_account)@company.com\shared_mailbox. I've tried that with and without passwords, but I get "ERROR [com.tek.cb.pr.localdbimport.EmailCheckerBean] Exception caught while checking email: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException".

When the program logs into outlook.office365.com, the debug messages show me

```
2017-03-14 15:07:44,145 INFO  [STDOUT] DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.4ea
2017-03-14 15:07:44,145 INFO  [STDOUT] DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc]
2017-03-14 15:07:44,145 INFO  [STDOUT] DEBUG: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
2017-03-14 15:07:44,145 INFO  [STDOUT] DEBUG: enable STARTTLS
2017-03-14 15:07:44,246 INFO  [STDOUT] * OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [TQBXAEgAUABSADIAMQBDAEEAMAAwADUANQAuAG4AYQBtAHAAcgBkADIAMQAuAHAAcgBvAGQALgBvAHUAdABsAG8AbwBrAC]
2017-03-14 15:07:44,246 INFO  [STDOUT] A0 CAPABILITY
2017-03-14 15:07:44,294 INFO  [STDOUT] * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 LOGINDISABLED STARTTLS SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+^M
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
2017-03-14 15:07:44,294 INFO  [STDOUT] DEBUG: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=<username>@<company>.com\<shared_mailbox>, password=<non-null>
2017-03-14 15:07:44,294 INFO  [STDOUT] A1 STARTTLS
2017-03-14 15:07:44,343 INFO  [STDOUT] A1 OK Begin TLS negotiation now.
2017-03-14 15:07:44,343 INFO  [STDOUT] A2 CAPABILITY
2017-03-14 15:07:44,607 INFO  [STDOUT] * CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+^M
A2 OK CAPABILITY completed.
2017-03-14 15:07:44,608 INFO  [STDOUT] IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: PLAIN
2017-03-14 15:07:44,608 INFO  [STDOUT] IMAP DEBUG: AUTH: XOAUTH2
2017-03-14 15:07:44,608 INFO  [STDOUT] A3 AUTHENTICATE PLAIN
2017-03-14 15:07:44,656 INFO  [STDOUT] +
2017-03-14 15:07:44,656 INFO  [STDOUT] YmNhbHZlcnRAbmV0c2NvdXQuY29tXGNhbHZlcnQgdGVzdABiY2FsdmVydEBuZXRzY291dC5jb21cY2FsdmVydCB0ZXN0AEhvdFdhdGVyMjQ=
2017-03-14 15:07:44,707 INFO  [STDOUT] A3 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

I've also tried disabling the different types of login authentication like "plain" and "xoauth2", but I have to have STARTTLS enabled. Has anybody tried this before? I'm using IMAP because the program always has before. Should I try SMTP?

Note that my problem is similar to this StackOverflow question, but this one deals with PHP: [Access Office356 shared mailbox with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481028/access-office356-shared-mailbox-with-php)

Comment: If you care, you may wish to edit out your password, but it appears to be a test account.  And also appears to be wrong. :)

Comment: You're using an ancient version of JavaMail; [please upgrade](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) if possible.  SMTP is for sending, not reading; you have to use IMAP.  Have you tried configuring Thunderbird to access the mailbox?  That would tell you if it's a JavaMail-specific problem or if you're doing something else wrong.  If you remove "\shared_mailbox" from the user name, and don't change the password, you can login, right?  If so, it sounds like you're doing the right thing and you may need to ask Microsoft for further help.

Comment: Yes, if I removed the shared_mailbox from my login, the program will login to my account fine and read my email. This program was written around 2011, so that is why javamail is so old. If I upgrade javamail, will I have to upgrade the Java JDK also?

The DEBUG statements just show password=<non-null> rather than showing the actual password in the debug messages.

Comment: The password is base64 encoded in the AUTHENTICATE string.