# Can't connect to Office 365 using php imap_open

Tags: php, ssl, office365, imap

I am trying to connect to Office 365 using PHP Imap but it won't connect with Office 365.  Everything works fine for gmail and other email hosts but on Office 365 I get a can not authenticate (I am sure the email and password are correct).

Server has an SSL certificate and IP Address has been whitelisted in Office.  I am thinking it is something to do with the hostname.

This is what I am currently trying:

```
{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl}
```

Also tried:

```
{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}
```

And

```
{outlook.office365.com:993/ssl}
```

**UPDATE**
It looks like this may be because this is a shared account based on the screenshot.  Would this change my hostname?

[image]

Comment: If the account has two-step authentication, you will need to generate an application specific password.

Comment: Thanks @Max it does not have two-step authentication enabled.

Comment: Reviewed this answer based on my findings but I still get Authentication error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28481028/access-office356-shared-mailbox-with-php

Answer (score 2):

Please try use the /authuser method.

```
imap_open("{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/authuser=user@maindomain.com}", "user@maindomain.com", "password");
```

Comment: Receive the error: `Error opening mailbox: Can not authenticate to IMAP server: AUTHENTICATE failed.` I just updated the question with an update, it looks like this may be a shared address, would that affect my hostname?

Comment: In that case, please specify the user too using the following (/user=):

imap_open("{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/authuser=user@maindomain.com/user=shared@anotherdomain.com}", "user@maindomain.com", "password");

Answer (score 1):

If certificates are not to be validated, use the "novalidate-cert" in the connection

```
 imap_open("{outlook.office365.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert/authuser=$user/user=$user}", $user, $pass);
```

this should work